# how to render vuejs components in dynamically added html from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component in a html that is returned from jquery ajax call but it doesn't render the component. so how to make vuejs render this component from jquery?

jquery code sample :

```
$.post(baseURL + "media", postData, function (data) {
      if(data.status == true) {
           $('#media_lib_app').html(data.view);
      }
 });
```

and what is returned inside the data.view is :

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

but when the data.view is added to the html div it doesn't render the component.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: the actual code is too big as its an old project that was relying on jquery but this is the exact situation as explained in the post

Comment: You'll be more likely to get help if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your issue.

Comment: ok i'll edit the post to add some code :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly you get a tag of a custom component from your AJAX call and want to build a Vue component out of it.

So let's say this is your `<test-component>`:

```
Vue.component('test-component', {
  template: "<p>I am the test component template</p>",
  methods: {
      // Component logic...
  }
});
```

Now somewhere in your app, you make the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = '<test-component></test-component>';
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; 
    
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    
    var res = Vue.compile(html)
    new Vue({
      render: res.render,
      staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
    }).$mount('#media_lib_app')
    
  }.bind(this));
})
```

Your component mounting point:

```
<div id="media_lib_app"></div>
```

More about .compile:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

**Note: `Vue.compile()` is only available in the full build.**

You can find here an working example:

https://jsbin.com/motuvokeha/edit?html,js,output

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: yes but the problem is that the ajax call happen in jquery code not vue code and at this time we can't change this part to vue so the question was how to do what you wrote but from jquery not vue

Comment: @m_elbardeny I edited the answer. As you can see now the code is made just in a jQuery block. However, to use a Vue component you need to register it first, so Vue knows what to do with it. I hope you understand that you can't just get an HTML tag and expect Vue magically figure things out :)

That said inside the AJAX callback you mount and compile the already registered component. I believe there is no other way.

Hope this time I got it :)

Comment: will this work if i'm using webpack ? i tried it and javascript throws error Vue is not defined

Comment: @m_elbardeny first make sure that you are **using the full build** of Vue, then you have to import Vue in your file `import Vue from 'vue'` if using ES6 or `var Vue = require('vue')`