# How to render a custom component into a map's marker popup?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a Vue plugin component [Timeago](https://github.com/egoist/vue-timeago), and i want to show a timeago time in the content of a map plugin. A super-simplified example to illustrate the usage would be something like:

```
let popup = L.responsivePopup().setContent(`
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>A thing happened <Timeago datetime="${datetime}"></Timeago></p>
`);
L.marker([lat, lon]).bindPopup(popup).addTo(this.map);
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555663/3788043), and [Vue's documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile), i should be able to compile this using `Vue.compile()`, but i am not understanding the concept.

First, there is no explanation on what a "full build" is. How can i tell if what i have is a "full build"? Searching for "vuejs full build" doesn't return anything that is being referred to as literally that phrase, even though they use it in the documentation there. All i know is that when i try to call `Vue.compile()` with having imported `import Vue from 'vue'`, it complains saying:

> TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.compile is not a function

So i don't know where to go from there.

And then second thing is (assuming the first thing gets sorted), will i have to make my HTML hold an empty div with a specific `id`, wait for it to render, and then call the `Vue.compile()` on it, since the sample code there runs with `.mount()` on an element id? Because that seems a little "incorrect", having seemingly an extra step. Or is that the only way to make this scenario work?

If there is an alternative simpler wait of making this work, like getting the `Timeago` component to just return the rendered string only, such as `2 hours ago` that i can incorporate into my string literal, that would work for me as well. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vue has differents build of it's package, `full` means that package can compile templates and and run it. All build types can be found here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds

Vue.compile allows you to use render functions, which allow you to manipulate DOM and create elements in a programmatic way. Here you can find Vue documentation about it https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

About the issue you are facing, you can create a vue component and put that popup inside it, this component when render will render the timeago component.

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>A thing happened <Timeago datetime="${datetime}"></Timeago></p>
</template>

import Timego from './Timeago.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        Timeago
    },

    props: {
        datetime: String
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm not understanding how either of these help. The first part about the render functions, that seems like a replacement for writing HTML, but it doesn't seem like a method of getting the rendered HTML out "on demand". In my situation, what happens is that on a user click, i create essentially a new DOM element "myself" (through Leaflet that is), to which i provide just static HTML to show in the popup. So i don't see where the mechanism is where i would tell vue to "run" this `Timeago` component to turn "2019-09-02" into "today", and give that whole result back to me. You know?